# Multiple inputs In Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to add an input from where it lets the user add multiple languages and saves them as a list.

for example, the user can enter English, Spanish, Arabic and saves each input as a list to the same field
Something similar to the tags field in Stack Overflow when adding tags [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR1sF.jpg)

Comment: HTML's select has a multiple attribute you can use. There's also libraries out there you can use to achieve an interface close to what stackoverflow uses for tags. For example: https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/ Another one is https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send multiple options , you can use select 2 js plugin :
[https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage][1]

use  script src in your template , and then :

```
<script>
    $('.multi-select').select2();
</script>
```

and then , in your html code do something like this :

```
 <select class='multi-select form-control' multiple=''
 data-placeholder='Enter Tags' aria-hidden='true'  name='tags[]'>
 <option value="1">tag 1</option>
 <option value="2">tag 2</option>
 <option value="3">tag 3</option> 
</select>
```

> notice that the key is your select element's name should be an array ;

hope that would work .